# JQuery change siblings select css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanted to change two border css to red if the month and year is over. I face an issue where i do not know how to call the siblings select.

This jquery isn't fully complete. I just like to know how to change the sibling select border color as well:

```js
$('.month').on('change', function() {
  var current_date = new Date();
  var current_month = current_date.getMonth();
  var current_year = current_date.getFullYear();
  var m = $(this).val();
  var month = $(this).closest('select');
  var year = month.siblings('.year');
  var y = year.val();
  if (m <= current_month + 1) {
    $('.month').css("border", "1px solid red");
    $('.year').css("border", "1px solid red");
  } else {
    $('.month').css("border", "1px solid grey");
    $('.year').css("border", "1px solid grey");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-left:1%;">
  <select class="month">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February </option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
  <select class="year">
    <option value="21"> 2021</option>
    <option value="22"> 2022</option>
    <option value="23"> 2023</option>
    <option value="24"> 2024</option>
    <option value="25"> 2025</option>
    <option value="26"> 2026</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing here?

Comment: Weird previously i tested out the code but it can't run out the border color for year. But somehow this coding that i posted works. To answer your question, currently the problem is solve xD thx

Comment: Your function will work only if the month field is changed

Comment: Previously I changed the month it did not work somehow when i show this incomplete coding it works